# Number of permutations of "LILAC" such that no letter is in its original position

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Given word: **LILAC**

It is given that the two $L$'s are *indistinguishable* and need to calculate the number of permutations of the word such that no character in the permuted word appears in its original position.

The way I approached is to find the number of derangements of 5 objects (treating the two $L$'s as distinct) and then dividing the answer by $2!$ giving $\frac{44}{2} = 22$.

Some are claiming that the answer is $12$ instead of $22$.

Is $22$ the wrong answer ? If yes, then how and why ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you divide by $2$?  You need to exclude all the derangements in which either (or both) $L_2$ winds up in the first slot or $L_1$ winds up in the third slot.  Easier to count directly, I'd say.

Comment: @lulu I thought we could apply the same line of reasoning how we do with permutations of objects (with few similar ones among them)

Comment: In some cases we divide to take a symmetry into account.  Here, for instance, if I asked how many permutations of those letters there were, the answer would be $\frac {5!}2$ since swapping the two $L's$ doesn't change the permutation.  I don't see any such symmetry at work in the given problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't understand the logic behind dividing by $2$.  To do this via derangements, you'd need to exclude the derangements in which the second $L$ winds up in the first slot and/or the first $L$ winds up in the third slot.

To count by hand:

There are three choices for the first slot, and then two for the third slot.

That leaves one letter out of $I,A,C$ unchosen and there are two slots that one might occupy.  After that, the $L's$ must go in the two unfilled slots.

Hence the answer is $$3\times 2\times 2 =12$$